# Is there a CSS method to scroll a div when the mouse is positioned anywhere on the page?

Tags: css, scrollbar

There are some questions around this topic but most of them are a few years old.

I am just wondering if there's a way to layout your page, such that the scrollwheel will scroll a specific div regardless of where the mousewheel is.

For example, on stackoverflow if you scroll down the homepage you will see the left hand menu stays fixed, and you can scroll it while the mouse is hovering over the menu, even when the mouse is hovering over the title bar. It may however be using javascript, I don't know.

Before I delve into the javascript solutions I wondered if CSS has enabled this, perhaps with a default div or some other CSS technique.

Here's a fiddle of my layout: https://jsfiddle.net/thjyf5c3/

```
<body style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height:100vh; overflow-y: hidden">
    HEADER FOR THE PAGE

<div style="flex-flow: column; display:flex;flex:1">
        <div style="flex: 1; display:flex;">
            <div style="background-color: red; max-width: 200px; min-width: 100px; flex-basis: 20%">test</div>
            <div style="background-color: purple;flex: 1; display: flex">

                <div style="flex-grow:1; position: relative; overflow:hidden; ">
                    <div style="position:absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow-y: scroll">
                        <div style="flex: 1; display:flex;">
                            <span style="font-size:500px">a<br />b<br />c<br /> </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
            <div style="background-color: blue;flex: 1">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As you can see it does not scroll if the mouse isn't in the bounds of the grid.

Comment: Basically... **no**!

Comment: the example you gave of SO is because the navbar is within the scrolled area and made to be sticky there

Comment: the real question is: what happen if I have 2 scrollable area in the same page? which one should scroll and when?

Comment: I see, I think there is no choice then but to use javascript. Thanks. The two scrollable area problem wouldn't be an issue, I was hoping for some css property such as "default-scroll", or perhaps a way to nest or connect the divs together. CSS has improved quite considerably over the past year or two so I thought I'd check to save myself a headache.